# Change the Price for All Products

Tags: database, magento, magento-1.9, price

I am using Magento version 1.9.3.4 and having around 6000 products in my stores with varies categories. Now I need to change the product **price by increasing 8%** for all products.

I have tried adding excel sheet and importing it and its taking very longer time to import.

Is there any other options to change the Price for all products at same time?

Any ideas are welcome with thanks.

Comment: If you can connect db directly then connect execute update script

Answer (score 0):

You can try magmi to update prices quickly. Magmi is very fast in importing and updating products. You can create a CSV file with sku in one column and price in second column and magmi will update prices using that.

Answer (score 0):

Load all the products and use the below code to update the price of all products

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->setPrice($newPrice);
$product->save();
```